# Error while installing Haskell DJinn - base-3.0.3.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any

Tags: haskell, installation, cabal

I tried installing [Djinn](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn) by using cabal but got the following error -

```
$ cabal install djinn --verbose
Reading available packages...
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure djinn-2009.9.3. It requires base ==3.*
For the dependency on base ==3.* there are these packages: base-3.0.3.1 and
base-3.0.3.2. However none of them are available.
base-3.0.3.1 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
base-3.0.3.2 was excluded because of the top level dependency base -any
```

The error message is mysterious, shouldn't `base -any` allow base version 3.0.3.1?

Comment: What version of the Haskell platform do you use? What version of GHC?

Comment: GHC - 7.0.3,  Haskell Platform - 2011.2.0.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Haskell Mailing list:

> It's not a great error message. Now, base is a special package. It comes with ghc, and cannot be upgraded. That's why Cabal will rule out all base versions but the one you already have installed. If you have a recent ghc, that'll be base-4.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup looks like that is the reason for the strange error message!

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how to make it link to base-3. However in the case of djinn, it is very easy to get it to work with base-4. The only thing keeping it from working with base-4 is that the old exception system was moved from Control.Exception to Control.OldException. If you download the source for it, in the REPL.hs file change the import to Control.Exception to Control.OldException, and in line 29 change Control.OldException.catch .

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, GHC 7 does not ships `base` in version 3 anymore. The best idea would robably be to notify the maintainer (lennart*at*augustsson.net) to update the package. An ad-hoc fix would be to download the package from [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/djinn/2009.9.3/djinn-2009.9.3.tar.gz), unpack it and manually edit the file `djinn.cabal` so that the dependency on `base` is `base 4.*`. It may or may not work, but most times it's worth a try.

Comment: I already tried all that and compiling djinn with base 4 does not work :( However, my question was more about the error message itself. Why doesn't `base -any` allow using `base -3.*` ?

Comment: @Anupam I don't know either. Those messages are very confusing.